# Make an AlertDialog without using AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a custom `AlertDialog` that doesn't use the system style defaults when it uses the `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog` theme. I want it to use that theme, but I want to to have the same style as a `ListActivity` I have using that same theme. Different classes have different styles for the same theme, so it appears I need to create a subclass of the `DialogFragment`. Another restriction is that I want this dialog to be general. That is, I want to be able to conditionally add buttons, message, title, icon, and items. Hence, it seems that I can't just inflate a `DialogFragment` from an xml file (or I may be able to if I can create all possible elements I'd want, and then hide the ones I don't want. Is it possible to programmatically build a `DialogFragment` without inflating it from a single xml file?

**EDIT**

It looks like this could help: [Add controls to custom dialog programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421852/add-controls-to-custom-dialog-programatically)

I'm working on something using this answer: [Dynamically add table row in table and display it in dialog box in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799770/dynamically-add-table-row-in-table-and-display-it-in-dialog-box-in-android)

**Why doesn't the button appear when I use this code?**

The xml elements I added in layout do appear.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_dialog, container);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.post_dialog_layout);

    Button testButton = new Button(getActivity());
    testButton.setText("success");
    testButton.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(testButton);
    return contentView;
}
```

Comment: I think the question is going more and more confusing. Please consider to re-edit the entire text above and to get focus on the core problem getting rid of useless stuff. For instance: themes and styles have to do anything with your problem?

Comment: How your `onCreateView()` looks like? You should put the content setup  there instead of in `onCreateDialog()` method.

Comment: This is really confusing. I came here trying to figure out how to create an AlertDialog without using a Builder but there are like eight other topics mixed in with the main question.

Comment: @nmr Sorry about that, I've voted to close this question.

Answer (score -1):

Everything you need is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Basically in order to build the content of your dialog you should override `onCreateView(...)`, but if you want more control on the Dialog itself you can also override `onCreateDialog(...)`.

Builder pattern is there to help and smooth things, but if you prefer to build stuff your own you can build  `Dialog` instance as well as its content view full-programmatically, without even inflating XML and simply instantiating layout elements at runtime.

Comment: How could I, for example, use an instance of this Dialog to create a dialog with one button, and use another instance of this Dialog to create a dialog with two buttons?

Comment: Simply check your discriminating factor in your `onCreateView`/`onCreateDialog` and build your content accordingly (ie: using two different xml files)

Comment: Are you saying that I'll need to create a different xml file for every dialog I want to create, and I can't build it programmatically?

Comment: No, it was only an example. You can fill your Dialog full-programmatically as you need, just like any other `Activity`, `View`, etc. But sorry I still can't understand: if you have many different dialogs, why you should use the same fragment class?

Comment: Sorry @RosePerrone, can you please clarify if the problem persists?

Answer (score -3):

You can set arguments Bundle to created DialogFragment and then use them to configure your Dialog. Some of them may be optional and you can use it to detect which option dialog should contain(title, additional buttons, icon).

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import ru.daoffice.R;

public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "ArgTitle";

    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "ArgMessage";

    public static DialogFragment newInstance(String title, String message) {
        Bundle argumnets = new Bundle();
        argumnets.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        argumnets.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);

        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialogFragment.setArguments(argumnets);
        return dialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(getArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE))
            .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: This uses an `AlertDialog.Builder`, which I said I was trying to avoid.